# Unable to install debug APK on physical device when running react-native run-android - Failed to parse APK file: /data/local/tmp/app-debug.apk

Tags: android, react-native, gradle, apk

[image]

Tried

- cleaning the android build folder
- restarting the device
- cleaning the npm cache
  but nothing works.

And also unable to install the debug.apk manually - says apk is corrupted.

AndroidManifest.xml looks clean. Any help would be really appreciated because stuck here for hours.

Comment: Could you delete the previously generated debug apk file first on path showed in error then try?

Answer (score 0):

The issue was there were multiple modules in my app which was created by me and those apps had different gradle versions. After I matched them the issues were gone.

```
-classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.2.2")
+classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.3")
```